# What is the best practices, tips and gotchas for drawing on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

Im trying to draw large images (5000*5000 px) on HTML5 canvas.
What is the best practices for doing this?

- Should I use one canvas or many canvases (tiles way) for this?
- What should I use drawImage() or putImageData()?
- What about performance and memory usage in this cases?

Can you guys recommend best readings for this and share your personal experience?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I know so far:

[Double buffering images](https://coderwall.com/p/p4crrq) -> great for your speed.

[Anti-aliased images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861447/html5-canvas-drawimage-how-to-apply-antialiasing) -> awesome quality of images even if resized

[A good tip](http://ajaxian.com/archives/canvas-image-data-optimization-tip) -> If you plan on using putImageData()

My experience as a HTML5 Game dev is that these two practices are really great, I use them both.

[When displaying lots of complex objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) (I don't know if it's related, but might come in handy, it was really great to learn how to do this correctly)

Also; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579478/html5-canvas-optimization-for-large-images)

Comment: Double buffering is not needed for canvas. If you check out that article you linked the article is debunked in the comments. The other tips aren't bad though.

Comment: Well my bad. Might be the wrong link ! Very interesting read, though: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing it for, but if you plan on scrolling around a 5000px5000px image I would definitely break it up into sections or tiles and use `drawImage` to only draw the parts the user will see.

For drawing large images you will see a performance decrease using `putImageData` its what `drawImage` is there for. `putImageData` is amazing when doing anything with particles, etc. Basically when you are drawing lots of small pieces to the screen you can easily draw 100,000 objects using `putImageData`.

Performance and memory usage shouldn't be a problem if you are only drawing the sections the user can see, heck even the full 5000x5000 shouldnt be *too* much of an issue honestly. What you're doing is not uncommon at all most browsers should be able to handle it.

**[Here is a poor unfinished example I was working on for a previous employer](http://somethinghitme.com/pprojects/stratwalk/)** the example uses a ton of tiles, even implements collisions and pathfinding and runs fine. If I were to just draw out one big map image it would be around 10000x10000 if I remember correctly (each tile is 64x64)